# Chrome WebView: triggering native Android Share function

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, android-webview, share

Is it possible, by any chance to invoke Android's native share(file) functionality within Chrome WebView? I'm creating a hybrid Ionic AngularJS app, and would like to use the Android's native share functionality for files. I've tried different plugins, but all of them use custom share implementation for each of the apps present on the device, which does not suffice.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do in Android? It sounds like Intent/Intent Filters: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html but are you perhaps mistaken about what the sender app is required to do and what a receiver app is required to do.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if what I'm asking is at all possible to do within Android WebView. Basicaly, in my WebView(Ionic Hybrid APP), I have a link to file on a remote server. I'd like to pick that file up, and simply invoke Share functionality, the one I can do with any file on my phone.

Comment: Just with Android WebView no. With additional Java code and a Javascript Interface - i.e. a Cordova plugin yes. There does appear to be a Cordova plugin which does what you want: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin If you have looked at, please expand on how it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I did. As far as I can tell, it supports a set of social services to share with, along with a limited set of endpoints you could use. This said, if I use native share button on my android device, it loads my latest chats, services I used that i could share this file with, and such.

Comment: [Removed rudeness] If the receiver app states in its manifest it can handle images/text/whatever it gets added to the share list. No change is made to the sender app, so any new app (social media/cloud service/whatever) will get added to the list as long as the mime type is supported along with the cost of the user needing to scroll when the list gets too long. See: ACTION_SHARE_EVENT in the plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java A quick glance shows most valid mime types so I expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried it to making an `JavascriptInterface`

Add this in your `MainActivity.java`

```
public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {
        private Context context;

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void sharingIsCaring(String code) {
            openSharing(code);
        }
}
```

This is the action that starts the sharing:

```
public void openSharing(String code) {
        String message = "Your share message: " + code;
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share your code"));
    }
```

So, how do you trigger the `@JavascriptInterface`

You need to add this in your `OnCreate()` method:

```
view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "SmashIt");
```

So to trigger it from the JS you only need to call the function `sharingIsCaring()`

You need to do that by placing `SmashIt` for the function that you call so Android will know it's him you are calling. So it will look like this:

```
SmashIt.sharingIsCaring(code)
```